# How to increment a python "bytes" object

Tags: python, hex, byte, increment

What is the fasted way to increment a bytes object in Python3.7?  Consider the following:

```
>>> foo = '00000000000000000000000000000000'
>>> bar = binascii.unhexlify(foo)
>>> bar
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

I want to increment `bar` by 1, resulting in `b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01'`.

If I try `bar + 1`, I get:

```
>>> bar + 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't concat int to bytes
```

If I try `bar + b'1'`, I get:

```
>>> bar + b'1'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x001'
```

I know there must be a faster way to loop over the hexadecimal values than by going back to `foo` (a string), converting it to an int, incrementing it, converting back to a string, then doing `binascii.unhexlify` on it.  But I'm not familiar with these bytes objects.

**EDIT**

The ultimate usage I'm aiming for is to loop over many values of `plaintext` below, while keeping `KEY` constant.  I want to take `plaintext` from '0000000000000000000000000000000' to 'FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF' and compute each value.  I imagine it will take several years to complete, but I'm curious how fast it will go.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import binascii
KEY = binascii.unhexlify('AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEEFFFF00001111')
plaintext = binascii.unhexlify('11112222333344445555666677778888')
rijn = AES.new(KEY, AES.MODE_ECB)
ciphertext = rijn.encrypt(plaintext)
binascii.hexlify(ciphertext).decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The best solution to your problem may lie at a higher level than this.

Comment: Thanks, I added the context in the edit

Comment: Several years is a severe underestimate. If you had started this computation at the beginning of the universe, it still wouldn't be a percent of a percent of a percent of the way done by now.

Comment: :) I'm still curious to see it in action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm curious too.  Please post the full output of your program once it finishes running. lol...

You can move from integer to byte array in Python 3.2 using functions to_bytes and from_bytes. I think that's the missing piece in your little scheme.

So, bring in the data you want and then convert it to a number by interpreting it as a 'big-endian' number representation:

```
plaintext = binascii.unhexlify('11112222333344445555666677778888')
# also, we'll want to know our length later on
plaintext_length = len(plaintext)
plaintext_number = int.from_bytes(plaintext, 'big')
```

Now you can keep incrementing that number and then do with it as you wish. For instance, convert it back to a bytearray and / or print it out as hex:

```
plaintext_number += 1
new_plaintext = plaintext_number.to_bytes(plaintext_length, 'big')
new_hex = binascii.hexlify(new_plaintext)

print(f'Testing new string. This shouldnt take too long, almost done! {new_hex}')

new_ciphertext = rijn.encrypt(new_plaintext)
new_cipherhex = binascii.hexlify(new_ciphertext).decode('utf-8')
```

**In summary:** you can't increment a bytes array. You have to first interpret the bytes as something. We interpret it as a big-endian integer. Hang on to that integer and keep incrementing it. At each step, you can convert that integer back to a byte array or even back to a hex string if you like.

Comment: @rusty-lemur - If this solution answered your question, please mark the answer as accepted.